# How to properly update a collection based on deltas (changes)

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, mongodb

I need to update a MongoDB collection (which was generated from an array of objects) based on a new version of said array.

Say I have a JS array with objects that look like this:

```
{
   roomId: 123
   members: {
      member1 {
         name : "Alice"
      }
      member2 {
         name : "Bob"
      }
   }
}
```

so, after insertMany passing the whole array, every document in mongo look like this:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d474dc23d61e66cbac7ba83"),
    "roomId" : "123",
    "members" : {
        "member1" : {
            "name" : "Alice"
        },
        "member2" : {
            "name" : "Bob"
        }
    }
}
```

I get a new array everyday with the status of the rooms, and need to update the mongo collection accordingly. Some rooms may have disappeared, some new ones may been created, but more importantly members may have left or entered into rooms.

The legacy solution was

```
collection.deleteMany({ }) // clear all
        .then(() => collection.insertMany(wholeArray))
```

but that obviously generated a peak of insertions into mongodb (this collection could be huge)

The best approach I could think of was only rewriting rooms with changes (completely remove the whole room and write it again updated), but I think it can be improved:

```js
const newData = Object.values(whereDataComesFrom);

// What's on mongo
const mongoData = await collection.find({}).toArray();
mongoData.forEach(elem => delete elem._id); // remove mongo's id for comparison

// DELTA LOGIC:
// See if there are room coincidences
// coincidences: rooms that are in mongo and also in newData
// outdated: rooms that are in mongo but not in newData
const [coincidences, outdated] = _.partition(mongoData, mongoRoom =>
                newData.find(room => room.roomId == mongoRoom.roomId)
            );

// check if members for room in coincidences remained the same
// don't do anything with the ones that didn't change
const [same, changed] = _.partition(coincidences, room =>
                _.isEqual(room, newData.find(r => r.roomId == room.roomId))
            );


// updated: the ones that changed, I wanted from newData
const updated = newData.filter(room =>
                changed.map(rm => rm.roomId).includes(room.roomId)
            );

// newOnes: is in newData not in mongodb
const newOnes = newData.filter(room =>
                !mongoData.map(rm => rm.roomId).includes(room.roomId)
            );

const toRemove = outdated.concat(changed).map(rm => rm.roomId);
const toAdd = updated.concat(newOnes);

if (toRemove.length > 0 || toAdd.length > 0) {
   return collection.deleteMany({ "roomId": { '$in': toRemove } }) // clear only outdated or changed
                    .then(() => collection.insertMany(toAdd, { ordered: false })); // insert new version of changed and newOnes

            }
```

Forgot to mention that I'm using lodash for `_.isEqual()` and `_.partition()`

I would like to check recursively into every room to see if there was changes, and somehow keep track of those in order to a)remove users from a room they are not members anymore b) insert only the new members into their current rooms (not rewrite the whole room) c) remove or add rooms (with their members) when needed.

Comment: Once you've all the required data, why can't you have a function that would pick n number of ids out of a bunch of ids and process the DB operation using .findAndModify() (https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/findAndModify/index.html#examples), When I said a function to limit you can have something similar to (https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#eachLimit)

Comment: thanks @srinivasy was looking for an approach that can update many documents from an array of modified objects. I'm still stuck with this. Thanks!